# MKPointAnnotation title not showing and annotation not draggable

Tags: ios, mkannotationview, mobile-development, mkpinannotationview, mkpointannotation

I think those two are related and I'm probably doing something wrong here:

First I'm overriding viewForAnnotation - in order to put my custom Image

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // we avoid changing the user's location blue point
    if([annotation isKindOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]]) {
      return nil;
    }
    else
    {
    static NSString *SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"SFAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinAnnotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[self.mapToPin dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];

     if (!pinAnnotationView)
          {
              MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                 reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
                  UIImage *littleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"littleImage.png"];
                  // You may need to resize the image here.
                  annotationView.image = littleImage;
              
                  pinAnnotationView.draggable = true;
                  pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true;
                  pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true;
                  return annotationView;
          }
          else
          {
              pinAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;
          }
          return pinAnnotationView;
    }
    

}
```

It seems that pinAnnotationView's **draggable**, **canShowCallout** and **animatesDrop** are not working.

Then, I'm calling my method in my viewDidLoad to set the Annotation

```
-(void) setAnnotation:(NSString*)lat : (NSString*)lng
{
    _mapAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateForPin;
    coordinateForPin.latitude = [lat floatValue];
    coordinateForPin.longitude = [lng floatValue];
    [_mapAnnotation setCoordinate:coordinateForPin];
    [_mapAnnotation setTitle:@"sometitle"];
    [_mapToPin addAnnotation:_mapAnnotation];
}
```

It seems that [_mapAnnotation setTitle:@"sometitle"]; is not working anymore when I'm overriding viewForAnnotation.

Is this the right way to go? I have been browsing but didn't find any solution that could help. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the accidental reference to the wrong variable name. The `pinAnnotationView` is `nil` inside that `if` statement, so setting properties with that `nil` reference is a NOOP.

```objectivec
if (!pinAnnotationView) {
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                    reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];

    ...

    annotationView.draggable = true;      // not pinAnnotationView
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true;
    annotationView.animatesDrop = true;

    return annotationView;
}
```

---

FWIW, if targeting iOS 10 or later, you can register your own class and move your annotation view configuration code into that subclass. Furthermore, in iOS 11 and later you do not need `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` at all.

For example, in iOS 11 and later:

```objectivec
//  MyAnnotationView.h

@import MapKit;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyAnnotationView : MKPinAnnotationView

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and

```objectivec
//  MyAnnotationView.m

#import "MyAnnotationView.h"

@implementation MyAnnotationView

- (instancetype)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        ...

        self.draggable = true;
        self.canShowCallout = true;
        self.animatesDrop = true;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And then, in your `viewDidLoad`, you register this class.

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mapView registerClass:[MyAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];
    ...
}
```

You can then remove the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` implementation entirely.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this is helpful but maybe I'm missing something, I've done all the steps, it is now draggable but and I don't have my image showing anymore - back to default behavior. I didn't do any other changes than the one you mentioned.
Should I change anything with my setAnnotation() method (mentioned above) or use something different than MKPointAnnotation in it?

Comment: @TheGix - The `MKPinAnnotationView` is designed to show pins. It used to allow images, but they changed this a few iOS versions ago. If you want to use your custom images, then don't subclass `MKPinAnnotationView`, but rather just `MKAnnotationView`. (I didn't notice that while you were calling your variable a “pin annotation” but were really instantiating a `MKAnnotationView`, not a `MKPinAnnotationView`.) FYI, `MKAnnotationView` does not have `animatesDrop` property.